# How do I change my greeting for Pokemon GTS Negotiations?

Tags: pokemon-series

I have saw lot's of different Greetings in GTS Negotiations, like "Good Morning" as gifs.

1. How can i change mine greeting ?
2. Is there a way that I could use those "gifs" greetings ? or they are event only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about Black and White, then you need to go to your trainer card and click on the bottom of the card, where it shoud say something like: "Hello, I'm TRAINER. I'm pleased to meet you!" From there, you can change the words and phrases of what you want to say. To use the moving greetings, look at the ones titled "Special." If it isn't special, then it is somewhere on the lower left of the screen. Hope this helps.